# Duda en un ejercicio con condicion While

Tags: python, while

Hola he estado realizando ejercicios con la condicion While pero aun me cuesta entender su funcionamiento el ejericicio consiste en ingresar 10 notas y decir las notas mayores a 7 y menores, me he guiado con otros ejercicios y he conseguido sacarlo...

```
x=1
conta1=0
conta2=0 
while x <= 10:
  notas= int(input("Introduce las notas"))
  if notas >= 7:
    conta1= conta1+1
  else:
    conta2=conta2+1
  x=x+1
print("Las notas mayores a 7 son",conta1)
print("Las notas menores a 7 son",conta2)
```

Mi duda es que hace la sentencia conta1= conta1+1 ? <- Alli es donde se van guardando las notas?, ¿Porque al final tenemos que introducir x=x+1?, ¿Porque es necesario inicializarlo el conta1 y conta2 desde 0?

Gracias,

Comment: Conta1 y conta2 son los contadores de notas. Se deben  inicializar a 0 ya que antes de pedir las notas tienes 0 de cada tipo, como es natural.

Comment: gracias, puedes llegar a explicarme que hace lo demas de mi duda...

Comment: Conta1 y conta2 son los contadores de notas. Se deben  inicializar a 0 ya que antes de pedir las notas tienes 0 de cada tipo, como es natural. La última nota introducida por el usuario se guarda en la variable nota, las anteriores no se guardan. De hecho allí donde dice notas= int(input("Introduce las notas")) debería decir notas= int(input("Introduce las nota")). Nota1 lleva la cuenta de las notas mayores o igual a 7, conta2 lleva la cuenta de las que son inferiores a 7. Allí donde dice print("Las notas mayores a 7 son",conta1) debía decir print("Las notas mayores o igual a 7 son",conta1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=1
conta1=0
conta2=0 
while x <= 10:
  notas= int(input("Introduce las notas"))
  if notas >= 7:
    conta1= conta1+1
  else:
    conta2=conta2+1
x=x+1
print("Las notas mayores a 7 son",conta1)
print("Las notas menores a 7 son",conta2)
```

> Te comento que el x=x+1, ayuda a que el ciclo while no se haga
>   infinito pues ya que por cada iteración aumenta su valor en uno y se
>   termine la ejecución del programa cuando x sea menor o igual a 10, es
>   decir que vas a poder ingresar un máximo de 10 notas de calificación

---

> El uso de conta1, es la variable que va a almacenar el total de las
>   notas que ingresaste y que será usada para mostrar el mensaje Las
>   notas mayores a 7 son:, conta1; como observas hay 2 mensajes posibles tanto si las notas son mayores a 7 o si son menores a 7 entonces la variable conta1 guarda el numero de notas cuando ingresaste mas de 7

Comment: Gracias por esto @Alfredo Paz

Comment: de nada dime si te ayude?

Comment: Al usar conta1=conta1+1 = Estariamos guardando la nota en la variable conta1 que seria la que inciamos a 0 y sumando 1 hasta que termine el ciclo?

Comment: no, lo que hace ese fragmento de código es como indico en la explicación, hace que el while se ejecute 10 veces y despues de eso se detenga por que de lo contrario lo haria infinitamente